# Shuttle Sort Iteration going back through list?? How?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to finish my implementation of the shuttle sort algorithm which if a swap of 2 adjacent items is made it will go back to check the other items.

I can check adjacent items fine but how do I check the previous elements of the list using 2 for loops as shown in my code.

Any help or suggestions on how to approach this implementation of the algorithm would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
def ShuttleSort(List):
     for i in range(len(List)):
        for j in range(len(List)-i):
            if j == 0:
               if List[j] > List[j+1]:
                   List[j],List[j+1] = list[j+1],List[j]
               else:
                   pass
            elif List[j] > List[j+1]:
               List[j],List[j+1] = list[j+1],List[j]
```

Comment: do not name your variables `list,map,max,min,dict,set,str,int,float, ...` they are built in names that get shadowed by your variables. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html .. essentially you assign those names some other value than the function they represent.

Comment: also why are some named `List` and some `list` ?

Comment: Yes, I understand, but in my python only list is reserved List isn't. and they are different due to a typing error not intentional

Comment: Wikipedia says that the shuttle sort is also called a cocktail shaker sort. Here are a couple of links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Cocktail_sort#Python